# JSF selectMany folded like a dropdown

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to have a dropdown list that allows for multiple items to be selected but I can't seem to find a solution with `JSF2`.

I tried `h:selectManyMenu` and `p:selectOneMenu` and `h:selectManyMenu` and the `p:selectManyMenu`. But all of them either allow for only one item to be selected, or create a list that is already open and has all the items spread out on the page.

I need something like this:

[image: from primefaces showcase]

But closed when the user first goes to the page.

In other words something like `h:selectOneMenu` that allows multiple selections?

Comment: 'selectManyCheckbox' is creating checkboxes on the page (not in a dropdown) and 'selectManyMenu' doesn't have a way to open the dropdown. I tested it on Chrome and Firefox and I can scroll by using the arrow keys on my keyboard but nothing else.

Comment: I guess something like this, http://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/hlmri but modifying it to work with jsf is hours of work. Pretty disappointing.

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml ?

Comment: @stg Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. If you write it as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @Eddy: How come you can find non-primefaces releated examples AND complain but did **not** do a quick check of the PrimeFaces showcase... Pretty disappointing ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimeFaces is providing such a component. It is called *SelectCheckboxMenu*

[image: SelectCheckboxMenu]

See the PrimeFaces showcase for more details:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml

Comment: And with an [`p:overlayPanel`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/overlayPanel.xhtml) in combination with a button or any input, you can achieve anything that resembles functionality like this. E.g. (non-real-world-example) by putting a `p:selectManyMenu` inside it